# bitbake error when remove wayland in local.conf on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: yocto, bitbake, wayland, qtwayland, eglfs

I'm using Yocto Project 2.4 and i.MX6 Quad sabreSD platform.I build Yocto Project on my Ubuntu 16.04 computer.

I want to have qt5.9 library in my rootFS so I build my image with below command.

```
bitbake fsl-image-qt5
```

After that, I tried to remove wayland cause I want to use eglfs to play my application.
So I add below line into local.conf.

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "wayland"
```

Then try to bitbake fsl-image-qt5 again but this time I got below error.

```
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: qtxmlpatterns-5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: qtxmlpatterns-5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0 do_compile: Function     failed: do_compile (log file is located at /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-    wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-    gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/temp/log.do_compile.12439)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-    wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/temp/log.do_compile.12439
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j 4 MAKEFLAGS=-j 4 OE_QMAKE_COMPILER=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-    gcc  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a9 --    sysroot=/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-    poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot     OE_QMAKE_CC=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-    abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-    q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-    gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot     OE_QMAKE_CXX=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-    abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-    q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-    gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot     OE_QMAKE_CFLAGS= -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fdebug-prefix-    map=/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-    linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0=/usr/src/debug/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot-native= -fdebug-prefix-map=/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot=  OE_QMAKE_CXXFLAGS= -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fdebug-prefix-map=/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0=/usr/src/debug/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot-native= -fdebug-prefix-map=/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot=  -fvisibility-inlines-hidden OE_QMAKE_LINK=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot OE_QMAKE_LDFLAGS=-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed OE_QMAKE_AR=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ar OE_QMAKE_STRIP=echo OE_QMAKE_WAYLAND_SCANNER=/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/wayland-scanner OE_QMAKE_INCDIR_QT=/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot//usr/include/qt5
| cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-        q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-    gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qt5/qmake -o Makefile /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/src/src.pro ) && make -    f Makefile
| make[1]: Entering directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/src'
| cd xmlpatterns/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qt5/qmake -o Makefile /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/src/xmlpatterns/xmlpatterns.pro ) && make -f Makefile
| make[2]: Entering directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/src/xmlpatterns'
| make[2]: Nothing to be done for `first'.
| make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/src/xmlpatterns'
| make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/src'
| cd tools/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qt5/qmake -o Makefile /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/tools/tools.pro ) && make -f Makefile
| cd examples/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qt5/qmake -o Makefile /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/examples/examples.pro ) && make -f Makefile
| cd tests/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qt5/qmake -o Makefile /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/tests/tests.pro ) && make -f Makefile
| make[1]: Entering directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/tests'
| cd auto/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qt5/qmake -o Makefile /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/tests/auto/auto.pro ) && make -f Makefile
| make[1]: Entering directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/examples'
| cd xmlpatterns/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qt5/qmake -o Makefile /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/examples/xmlpatterns/xmlpatterns.pro ) && make -f Makefile
| make[1]: Entering directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/tools'
| cd xmlpatterns/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qt5/qmake -o Makefile /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/tools/xmlpatterns/xmlpatterns.pro ) && make -f Makefile
| cd xmlpatternsvalidator/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qt5/qmake -o Makefile /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/tools/xmlpatternsvalidator/xmlpatternsvalidator.pro ) && make -f Makefile
| make[2]: Entering directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-    q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/examples/xmlpatterns'
| cd xquery/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qt5/qmake -o Makefile /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/examples/xmlpatterns/xquery/xquery.pro ) && make -f Makefile
| cd recipes/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qt5/qmake -o Makefile /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/examples/xmlpatterns/recipes/recipes.pro ) && make -f Makefile
| cd filetree/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qt5/qmake -o Makefile /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/examples/xmlpatterns/filetree/filetree.pro ) && make -f Makefile
| cd schema/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qt5/qmake -o Makefile /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/examples/xmlpatterns/schema/schema.pro ) && make -f Makefile
| make[2]: Entering directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/tests/auto'
| cd checkxmlfiles/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-    wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qt5/qmake -o Makefile /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/tests/auto/checkxmlfiles/checkxmlfiles.pro ) && make -f Makefile
| cd cmake/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qt5/qmake -o Makefile /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/tests/auto/cmake/cmake.pro ) && make -f Makefile
| cd patternistexamplefiletree/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qt5/qmake -o Makefile /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/tests/auto/patternistexamplefiletree/patternistexamplefiletree.pro ) && make -f Makefile
| cd patternistexamples/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qt5/qmake -o Makefile /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/tests/auto/patternistexamples/patternistexamples.pro ) && make -f Makefile
| make[3]: Entering directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/examples/xmlpatterns/xquery'
| make[3]: Nothing to be done for `first'.
| make[3]: Leaving directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/examples/xmlpatterns/xquery'
| make[2]: Entering directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/tools/xmlpatterns'
| make[2]: Nothing to be done for `first'.
| make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/tools/xmlpatterns'
| make[3]: Entering directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/tests/auto/cmake'
| make[3]: Nothing to be done for `first'.
| make[3]: Leaving directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-    q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/tests/auto/cmake'
| cd patternistheaders/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qt5/qmake -o Makefile /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/tests/auto/patternistheaders/patternistheaders.pro ) && make -f Makefile
| make[2]: Entering directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/tools/xmlpatternsvalidator'
| make[2]: Nothing to be done for `first'.
| make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-    q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/tools/xmlpatternsvalidator'
| make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/tools'
| make[3]: Entering directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/tests/auto/patternistexamplefiletree'
| compiling /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/tests/auto/patternistexamplefiletree/tst_patternistexamplefiletree.cpp
| make[3]: Entering directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/examples/xmlpatterns/recipes'
| make[3]: Nothing to be done for `first'.
| make[3]: Leaving directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-    r0/build/examples/xmlpatterns/recipes'
| make[3]: Entering directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/examples/xmlpatterns/schema'
| make[3]: Nothing to be done for `first'.
| make[3]: Leaving directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-    r0/build/examples/xmlpatterns/schema'
| make[3]: Entering directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/tests/auto/checkxmlfiles'
| compiling /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/tests/auto/checkxmlfiles/tst_checkxmlfiles.cpp
| make[3]: Entering directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/examples/xmlpatterns/filetree'
| make[3]: Nothing to be done for `first'.
| make[3]: Leaving directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/examples/xmlpatterns/filetree'
| make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/examples/xmlpatterns'
| make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/examples'
| make[3]: Entering directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/tests/auto/patternistheaders'
| compiling /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/tests/auto/patternistheaders/tst_patternistheaders.cpp
| make[3]: Entering directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/tests/auto/patternistexamples'
| compiling /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/tests/auto/patternistexamples/tst_patternistexamples.cpp
| /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/tests/auto/patternistexamplefiletree/tst_patternistexamplefiletree.cpp:54:10: fatal error: tst_patternistexamplefiletree.moc: No such file or directory
|  #include "tst_patternistexamplefiletree.moc"
|           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| compilation terminated.
| make[3]: *** [.obj/tst_patternistexamplefiletree.o] Error 1
| make[3]: Leaving directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/tests/auto/patternistexamplefiletree'
| make[2]: *** [sub-patternistexamplefiletree-make_first] Error 2    
| make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
| /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/tests/auto/checkxmlfiles/tst_checkxmlfiles.cpp:96:10: fatal error: tst_checkxmlfiles.moc: No such file or directory
|  #include "tst_checkxmlfiles.moc"
|           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| compilation terminated.
| make[3]: *** [.obj/tst_checkxmlfiles.o] Error 1
| make[3]: Leaving directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/tests/auto/checkxmlfiles'
| make[2]: *** [sub-checkxmlfiles-make_first] Error 2
| /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/tests/auto/patternistexamples/tst_patternistexamples.cpp:346:10: fatal error: tst_patternistexamples.moc: No such file or directory
|  #include "tst_patternistexamples.moc"
|           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| compilation terminated.
| make[3]: *** [.obj/tst_patternistexamples.o] Error 1
| make[3]: Leaving directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/tests/auto/patternistexamples'
| make[2]: *** [sub-patternistexamples-make_first] Error 2
| /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/git/tests/auto/patternistheaders/tst_patternistheaders.cpp:124:10: fatal error: tst_patternistheaders.moc: No such file or directory
|  #include "tst_patternistheaders.moc"
|           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| compilation terminated.
| make[3]: *** [.obj/tst_patternistheaders.o] Error 1
| make[3]: Leaving directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/tests/auto/patternistheaders'
| make[2]: *** [sub-patternistheaders-make_first] Error 2
| make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/tests/auto'
| make[1]: *** [sub-auto-make_first] Error 2
| make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/build/tests'
| make: *** [sub-tests-make_first] Error 2
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at     /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtxmlpatterns/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+757fc81657-r0/temp/log.do_compile.12439)
ERROR: Task (/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/sources/meta-qt5/recipes-    qt/qt5/qtxmlpatterns_git.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 5855 tasks of which 5853 didn't need to be rerun     and 1 failed.
```

All the same steps that I did in Yocto Project 2.0 could work but Yocto Project 2.4 couldn't.

How to fix this error?

If I wish to use `-platform eglfs` to run my application, which way is the best to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstall Yocto project and it works.

I think there is something got wrong when I repo the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You should to add eglfs support to distro.

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = "eglfs"
```

Comment: I reinstall Yocto project and it works. I think there is something got wrong when I repo the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove tmp/ directory from your build directory and rebuild the whole thing again after every change in DISTRO_FEATURES